# Beyond Compare showing error File Not Found from Temp folder

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, beyondcompare4

I have **SourceTree** installed.

And have set up Beyond Compare as Diff tool.

When I click on a changed file in the Unstaged Files section, and press *Ctrl+D*. Which launches Beyond Compare.

It shows the difference perfectly.

But when I repeat the above steps for another file, I see error like below for the old version of file:

[image]

**Workaround:** I close the Beyond Compare and then press Ctrl+D on file in SourceTree, It works fine.

I tried changing the executable to **BComp.exe** in SourceTree Options.
But that also did not resolve the issue.
Please let me know any possible solution for this.

Comment: When it says file not found, does the file at that path actually exist, or is it pointing to the wrong path? If it's the wrong path, when you try again, does it show the proper path?

Comment: This happens only when I try to open a second file in the Beyond Compare

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of SourceTree broke built-in Beyond Compare integration. Editing your .gitconfig file might fix the problem.

1. Go into:  C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\etc
2. Edit the gitconfig file and add

   ```
   [difftool "sourcetree"]
   cmd = 'C:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe' $LOCAL $REMOTE
   ```

Reference: [Using Beyond Compare with Version Control Systems - SourceTree](https://www.scootersoftware.com/kb/vcs#sourcetree)

Comment: I am not able to find the gitfonfig in Program Files but changed the Arguments in the Source Tree->Options->Diff.
But it did not work.

Comment: This is usually caused by calling bcompare.exe instead of bcomp.exe from version control systems.

Using bcomp.exe opens every compare and merge in a separate helper process, allowing version control to detect when the comparison is complete.

Using bcompare.exe opens all comparisons in a single process, so version control can't detect when the comparison is complete if you launch more than one diff.

Comment: SourceTree has intermittently broken Beyond Compare integration in the past, it's possible there is a gitconfig file somewhere that is referencing bcompare.exe instead of bcomp.exe that is causing the problem.